# Why does this not compile in LaTeX PDF mode?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pstricks

The following, just compile when I do XeLaTeX mode. You can modify so I can build PDF LaTeX mode?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt,12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\pslegend[rt]
{
    \color{blue}\rule{5mm}{1mm} & \color{blue}$f(x)=e^x$ 

    \color{red}\rule{5mm}{1mm} & \color{red}$f(x)=\ln(x)$
}
\begin{psgraph}[algebraic]{->}(0,0)(-3,-3)(7,7){12cm}{!}

    \psplot[linecolor=blue]{-2.5}{2.5}{2^x}

    \psplot[linecolor=red]{2 -2.5 exp}{2 2.5 exp}{log(x)/log(2)}

    \psplot[linestyle=dashed]{-2}{6}{x}

\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you looked at `pdftricks`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compile directly via `pdflatex` provided: 1) you add the `pdf` option to the document class (it says to pstricks to load `auto-pst-pdf`; the `pstricks` option isn't useful, as the package is loaded by `pst-plot`; 2) you enclose the pstricks code in a `postscript` environment (there seems to be some problems with the `psgraph` environment); 3) you launch pdflatex with the `-shell-escape` switch (for TeX Live and Mac TeX), or `--enable-write18` (for MiKTeX):

```
\documentclass[pdf,border=15pt,12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}
    \pslegend[rt]
    {
        \color{blue}\rule{5mm}{1mm} & \color{blue}$f(x)=e^x$
        \color{red}\rule{5mm}{1mm} & \color{red}$f(x)=\ln(x)$
    }
    \begin{psgraph}[algebraic]{->}(0,0)(-3,-3)(7,7){12cm}{!}
        \psplot[linecolor=blue]{-2.5}{2.5}{2^x}
        \psplot[linecolor=red]{2 -2.5 exp}{2 2.5 exp}{log(x)/log(2)}
        \psplot[linestyle=dashed]{-2}{6}{x}
    \end{psgraph}
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The TikZ version of the diagram using package `pgfplots`, which is based on TikZ. Then pdfTeX in PDF mode can also be used to compile the document.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xmin=-3,
      xmax=6.5,
      ymin=-3,
      ymax=6.5,
      xlabel={$x$},
      ylabel={$y$},
      xtick={-3, ..., 6},
      ytick={-3, ..., 6},
      axis x line=middle,
      axis y line=middle,
      every axis x label/.append style={at={(axis cs:6.5, 0)}, right},
      every axis y label/.append style={at={(axis cs:0, 6.5)}, above},
      width=10cm,
      height=10cm,
    ]
      \addplot[blue, smooth] {exp(x)};
      \addlegendentry{$f(x) = e^x$}
      \addplot[red, domain=.0001:6.5, samples=250, smooth] {ln(x)};
      \addlegendentry{$f(x) = \ln(x)$}
      \addplot[dashed] {x};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]