# How to create a "bubble-like" callout for describing a graph function?

Tags: pstricks

I want to draw with PSTricks the following figure and I don't know how to draw the "bubble-like" callout. 
Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: @GodMustBeCrazy I am no TeXpert however you could suggest a hypothetical start point may be https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250468/170109

Comment: @GodMustBeCrazy yep that would require something similar to  \psWordBallon[options](text center)(arrow end){text width}{text} from https://tug.org/PSTricks/pst-node/Examples/WordBalloon.tex but I have other fish to fry (employer calls) so will have to leave an answer to others

Comment: Maybe the function is f(x) = e^(-x) instead of f(x) = e^x.

Comment: @GodMustBeCrazy Maybe. But in that case I think the horizontal axis should go from right to left not from left to right :))

Answer (score 11):

With `pstricks-add.tex` from http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/TeXnik/tex/generic/pstricks-add/

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-3,-1)(4,5.5)
\psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(-2.5,-1)(3.5,5)[$x$,-90][$y$,0]
\psyTick(1){1}\uput[225](0,0){0}
\psplot[algebraic,yMaxValue=4.5,linecolor=red,linewidth=1.5pt]{-2.5}{3}{Euler^(-(x))}
\psCallout(1,0.6){\scriptsize $f(x)=e^{-x}$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}

    \begin{pspicture}(-3,-1)(4,5.5)
    \psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(-2.5,-1)(3.5,5)[$x$,-90][$y$,0]
    \psyTick(1){1}\uput[225](0,0){0}
    \psplot[algebraic,yMaxValue=4.5,linecolor=red,linewidth=1.5pt]{-2.5}{3}{Euler^(-(x))}
    \psCallout(1,0.6){\scriptsize $f(x)=e^{-x}$}
    \psCallout[tipAngle=120,tipPos=0.6,linearc=0.5,
       fillcolor=blue!30,fillstyle=solid](-1,0.2){\shortstack{negative\\axis}}
    \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Really nice touch showing both styles but would match OP question if the two bubbles were reversed with red tone rather than blue or am I pushy / asking too much ?

Comment: Also no big deal ...

Answer (score 8):

A simple Ti*k*Z solution for comparison purpose only:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (0,-1)--(0,3) node[left] {$y$};
    \draw[->] (-3,0)--(3,0) node[below]{$x$};
    \draw[fill=black] (0,1) circle (0.5pt)  node[below left]{1};
    \draw (0,0) node[below left] {$O$};
    \draw plot[smooth,domain=-1:2.5] (\x,{exp(-(\x))});
    \node (root) at (1+0.1,1/e+0.1) {};
    \node[
        rectangle callout, 
        draw,
        yshift=1cm,
        xshift=2cm,
        callout absolute pointer={(root)}
    ] {\scriptsize $f(x)=e^{-x}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]